# Downloading Parse.com crash reports?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a way to download the crash reports from Parse.com? I've looked through the documentation and the site, but no luck.

(I'm having problems symbolicating a crash report, and despite uploading the relevant dSYM files, it's just not happening. I may have better luck symbolicating them directly on my machine.)